# Getting TypeError on simple mathematical function

Tags: python

```
def num(a, t):
    a = str(a)
    t = str(t)
    exp = int(t[len(t) - 2]) + 1
    for i in range(len(a)):
        stuff = sum(2 * (exp ** i))
    if float(stuff % int(t)) == 0:
        print("katıdır")
    else:
        print("katı değildir")
```

I'm trying to write a simple general mathematical formula that'd help me calculate whether the number `t` is a multiple of number `a`, but I get the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` on this line:

```
stuff = sum(2 * (exp ** i))
```

The issue probably arises from the variable `exp` being an integer, but I couldn't find a way to go around this.

Comment: `sum` expects an iterable, so it can add multiple things together, `sum([1, 2, 3]) == 6`. You're passing an integer, which isn't iterable.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks! I just placed the argument inside sum within square brackets and that fixed it!

Comment: But there's no point if you only have one thing, `sum([x]) == x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that sum() needs a list (or iterable) and you're giving an integer to it...

I'm not sure about what you're trying to do. But if you want to know if `t` is a multiple of `a` here is a function that does that returning a boolean (`True` if `t` is a multiple of `a`, `False` otherwise) :

```
def num(a, t):
    return t % a == 0



print(num(2, 5))
print(num(2, 4))
```

Output :

```
False
True
```

Comment: You posted this at the same time I fixed the issue. Thanks!

I'm trying to understand whether if the formula I specified above is correct for all states, so I'm basically trying to create something that could be practical for pen & paper purposes and verifying its accuracy on Python.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched `stuff = sum(2 * (exp ** i))` to `stuff = sum([2 * (exp ** i)])`, thus allowing the argument inside `sum` to become an iterable (thanks to @jonrsharpe for explanation).

Here's the final code:

```
def num(a, t):
a = str(a)
t = str(t)
exp = int(t[len(t) - 2]) + 1
for i in range(len(a)):
    stuff = sum([2 * (exp ** i)])
if float(stuff % int(t)) == 0:
    print("katıdır")
else:
    print("katı değildir")
```